# Sidekiq jobs running endlessly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using `rails 5` and `sidekiq (4.1.2)` on `Heroku`
and calling delay on a class method written in my User model
like:

```
delay.mass_invite_through_csv(mass_invitation.id, current_user, data)
```

here mass_invitation is a object of MassInvitation Class and current_user is current_user, and data is a hash params.

now this method is getting executed infinitely.

In my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

in my config/sidekiq.yml

```
concurrency:  3
```

everything is working correctly locally, please help.

Comment: is there an crash logs for Sidekiq jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq retries failed jobs automatically, therefore you have to understand why it is failing first. 2 possible solutions here: `tail` into sidekiq output either mount sidekiq dashboard to your app and look whats wrong there.

[Guide to install the dashboard](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring)